# Extraer info de archivos XML

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, funciones, txt

Les cuento que necesito extraer una informacion (en Python) de varios archivos XML, ordenarla y escribir archivos txt, el asunto es que algunos archivos no tienen toda la informacion. En este caso la etimologia de una palabra. Entonces yo debo escribir en el txt la etimologia (si esta en el XML) y si no, pues queda en blanco. Y no logro extraer nada, no hace nada, no parece ni entrar a buscar lo que esta alli. Les dejo parte del codigo

```
def get_etym(tree):
    etym = []
    root = tree.getroot()  
    for entry in root.iter("entry"):
        if entry.find("etym/mentioned"):
            etym.append(entry.find("etym/mentioned").text)
            print(etym)
    return etym

for filename in glob.glob( os.path.join("in/LettreA", '*.xml') ):
    tree = ET.parse(filename)
    etimo = get_etym(tree)
    print(etimo)
```

Y parte del archivo XML

```xml
<entry>
  <form>
    <orth>ABAISSER</orth>
    <date>16/01/2017T11h05mn</date>
    <valid>true</valid>
    <auteur>sanchez.adeline</auteur>
  </form>
  <gramgrp>
    <gram type="pos">verbe trans. et pronom.</gram>
  </gramgrp>
  <etym>
    <bibl>
      <etymosrc>FEW I 273a :</etymosrc>
    </bibl>
    <mentioned>bassiare</mentioned>
  </etym>
  <sense mod="MED." med="MED.">
```

Muchas gracias :) de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tres cosas:

Primero, recuerda subir el código con sus imports respectivos para ver que librerías estás utilizando. Por los objetos que utilizas imagino que estás usando algo como `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET`

Segundo: verifica que estés leyendo los archivos correctamente. Para esto, imprime "filename" al comienzo del ciclo for y comenta el resto (solo para verificar, después puedes eliminarlo).

Tercero: tomando como referencia el extracto que subiste (puede requerir alguna modificacion adicional) tu función get_etym se puede simplificar a:

```
def get_etym(tree):
    etym = []
    root = tree.getroot()
    for mentioned in root.findall("etym/mentioned"):
        etym.append(mentioned.text)
    return etym
```

En el ejemplo publicado se retorna (etym): ['bassiare']

Buena suerte!